# EclipseLink JPA query not working

Tags: oracle, jpa, eclipselink, spring-batch

I have an sql query as below

```
select pset.psetID
  from PlanPlanSet pset
  left join Excludedplans eld
    on pset.plnNBR = eld.plnNBR
 group by pset.psetID
having count(pset.plnNBR) = count(eld.plnNBR)
```

I am trying to write Eclipse link JPA query for the same as below

```
select pset.psetID from PlanPlanSetDO pset LEFT JOIN ExcludedPlansDO eld ON eld.plnNBR=pset.plnNBR GROUP BY pset.psetID HAVING COUNT(pset.plnNBR)=COUNT(eld.plnNBR)
```

It seems something goes wrong here and my SPRING BATCH reader is not taking this query. Can somebody help me with this?

I cross verified all he DO classes and the fields.

Entity classes

**PlanPlanSetDO.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name='PlanPlanSet')
class PlanPlanSetDO{
@Id
@Column(name='psetID')
private String psetID;

@Column(name='plnNBR')
private String plnNBR;
//getters and setters.
}
```

**ExcludedPlansDO.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name='Excludedplans')
class ExcludedPlansDO{
@Id
@Column(name='plnNBR')
private String plnNBR;
//getters and setters.
}
```

JPA service provider logs are not available on executing this query. all the logs are available till this query.

Comment: wonder what "not working" means. wonder what is in the JPA providers log. wonder what the entity classes are that relate to this.

Comment: @DN1 added the entity classes. Logs are not available

Comment: If I simply give "select pset.psetID from PlanPlanSetDO pset" its working. and the above query gives result in query browser as well

Comment: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#LEFT_JOIN I referred this link

Comment: are you getting an error or exception that might indicate the problem?  My guess is the having clause is causing a problem, but you would have to test to confirm if that is the issue and the exception should tell you the exact problem or help narrow it down.